# How do speed and density change in a turbulent flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, navier-stokes, turbulence, vortex

Suppose a fluid passes from having laminar flow, to having a turbulent flow (like when passing after an object). How do fluid speed and fluid density change after that?

[image: turbulent flow]

Comment: I assume you mean the *average* speed and density, as the instantaneous values in a turbulent flow are highly complex and chaotic. Also, I think you need to be clearer about the flow situation: is this in a pipe? External flow? Is it incompressible/compressible?

Comment: The speed is fluctuating around a mean value. It is an interplay between rising instabilities and decaying developed instabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Velocity;
In the case of pipe flow, the velocity remains constant simply through continuity, and the losses are influencing only to pressure. 
In the open channel flow the velocity depends on up- and downstream conditions, and can therefore even be higher after the object, but also lower if the object causes a hydraulic jump.

Density;
In the pipe flow the density is influenced only through the thermal expansion caused by the pressure turning to heat. 
In the open channel flow the density can change quite a lot if air entrainment occurs.
The Turbulence has only indirect influence to density.

Comment: I assume here you are referring to the mean values? This answer seems to be assuming the flow is internal, within a pipe, which is not made clear in the question. Also, I'm not sure if open-channel flow is relevant - the effects of turbulence there may be very different to non-open flows.